# Use specific localization in Cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, localization

How can you make your cocoa app use a specific locale / localization thats different from what the current locale says?

My app has a number of localizations and I would like to be able to choose the localization the app uses in a config file. How can I tell Cocoa which of the localizations to use?

Comment: Only add one localization for the config file.

Comment: [This][1] can help you. It's the best way I think! Good luck.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594222/detect-localization-xcode-6-mac-cocoa

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm could it be that AppleLocale expects an 'en' and not an "en_US"?

'en' works for me in the terminal so... I don't see why it should not be the same string here for you as well when setting it in your app

defaults write com.mycompany.myproduct AppleLocale 'en'

Answer (score 1):

Set the `AppleLanguages` array in the application's user defaults to contain the one you'd prefer to use, and set an appropriate `AppleLocale` string in the defaults too. Having said that, *why* use a localisation which isn't the one the user prefers?

Comment: The concept of a "user" is misleading for this app, as it assumes the user owns the machine. This is a kiosk style app run on my companies hardware, which is always set to the same locale. There is a central configuration which dictates all settings, including the GUI language.

Comment: One reason is to test localization changes, such as to make sure a string received from a localizer fits into the control where it's displayed in the UI, or to make sure you didn't break anything while repeating a non-string edit across multiple localizations of a nib.

Comment: @Peter: yes, I do that myself. But that's not the use case that I inferred from the question.

Answer (score 1):

according to MAAD's answer.
I tested in my app and found the only key that affects is `AppleLanguages`

so

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"en"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

is enough.

Remember to restart your app to make user defaults take effects.

Answer (score 0):

I tried setting "AppleLocale" and "AppleLanguages" with something like the following:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"en"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"en_US" forKey:@"AppleLocale"];
```

It did nothing though, still the language and locale from the system preferences are used.

Comment: Seems to work, but only after restarting the program.
Meaning: First time the program starts with changed settings it sets the user defaults using the above code. Subsequent calls to NSLocalizedString dont use the newly set language/locale though, until I restart the program.