# Overriding preferred strings localization on the fly for testing

Tags: cocoa, localization, nsbundle, nslocalizedstring

Using the Settings app in the iPhone simulator to switch languages is a PITA way of testing localization tweaks. I'm trying to figure out a way to switch localizations (en/fr/es/etc) on the fly in my app with a debug setting without restarting the app.

NSBundle provides ways of requesting localized resources from an arbitrary localization, e.g.

```
- (NSString *)pathForResource:(NSString *)name ofType:(NSString *)extension inDirectory:(NSString *)subpath forLocalization:(NSString *)localizationName
```

But I find no equivalent for the string management subsystem. It sounds from [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669645/how-to-force-nslocalizedstring-to-use-a-specific-language) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305564/use-specific-localization-in-cocoa-app) that you can override the registered defaults, which sounds goofy and requires an app restart.

Are there any other strategies here? If I wrapped NSLocalizedString with something that in debug builds did its own work, what's the shortest path to loading a given `.strings` file? Is there a programmatic way to access those strings tables without going and parsing them raw myself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do this that I've figured out is by using the subtle trick suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669645/how-to-force-nslocalizedstring-to-use-a-specific-language/1746920#1746920). You can wrap `NSLocalizedString()` in a function that knows about a localization "override", and chooses how to get its strings based on whether that is set. When you want to override, you can create a "sub bundle" from the localization's directory, and then pull string from that bundle. Here's the gist of it:

```
if (CurrentLocalization != nil) {
    NSBundle * locBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:CurrentLocalization ofType:@"lproj"]];
    return [locBundle localizedStringForKey:key value:nil table:nil];
} else {
    return NSLocalizedString(key, @"");
}
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

The trick to use specific language by selecting it from the app is to force the NSLocalizedString to use specific bundle depending on the selected language ,

here is the post i have written for this http://learning-ios.blogspot.com/2011/04/advance-localization-in-ios-apps.html

and here is the code of one sample app https://github.com/object2dot0/Advance-Localization-in-ios-apps

Answer (score -1):

Set the `AppleLanguages` default to an array consisting of the preferred languages, most preferential first. For example if you only care about English, set it to `'("en");'`

Comment: Hey Graham, thanks for the quick reply. I really hate to be That Guy, but I did note that I was looking for an on-the-fly solution that doesn't require an app restart, and linked to your answer to previous related questions. Looks like I'll need to parse the strings plist directly.

Comment: @quixoto are you saying that if you programmatically update the `AppleLanguages` default, it _doesn't_ affect which strings table is used?

Comment: It did, but seemed to do so only after restarting the app. Presumably the locale subsystem initializes/caches the string table at app start time?

Comment: Unfortunately, this trick only works after restarting the app. (Tested on iPad with iOS 3.2)