# Language change after selecting a option from the drop down list in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, localization

I was working with language localisation .I want to change the language of my application whenever i select a language from a drop down list which is present in my application , that is it should change the language without changing the language of device .please suggest me how can i implement

Thanks in advance

Comment: As always, consider whether it's both in your users' interest and worth your time to circumvent the standard system behavior here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this: [How to force NSLocalizedString to use a specific language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669645/how-to-force-nslocalizedstring-to-use-a-specific-language/1746920#1746920)

Comment: hey i followed your link, its really helpful partly.In one example they are selecting a language on click of a button , but my doubt is can i set it through a pickerview ,i.e on selecting from the list in pickerview the language should change

Comment: Have an array of country codes like @"it", @"de" and use it to fill up the picker. Then just use the picker delegate method to switch languages: `- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component { [Language setLanguage: [_array objectAtIndex: row]]; //some code to update the view (labels and everywhere different language is used) }`. If I understood your question correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but it won't play nicely with the built in localization functions in Foundation (e.g. `NSLocalizedString`), so you'll need to ignore them and write your own string-getting function, XIB-loading path, etc.

The question and answer here covers how to access localizations in the bundle on the fly like this: 
[Overriding preferred strings localization on the fly for testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118031/overriding-preferred-strings-localization-on-the-fly-for-testing)

Answer (score 0):

You can force the "AppleLanguages" user default.
The example below shows how can be done; in particular here I'm switching the first (default) with the second language.

```
    NSArray *lang = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    NSLog(@"current lang: %@",lang);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                      [lang objectAtIndex:1],
                                                      [lang objectAtIndex:0],
                                                      nil]
                                              forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableArray *languages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[defaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"]];

    [languages replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"fr"];

    [defaults setObject:languages forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    [defaults synchronize];
```

This is setting the language to French. Just put on position 0 what language you want to be loaded.