# Detect localization (xCode 6 MAC Cocoa)

Tags: macos, localization

How can I detect the localization?

I want something like:

if localization is german...

else...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"German" is not a complete localization. It is just a language. OS X allows the user to order their language preferences, so it is completely possible that your application is displaying in German but the user's preferred language is Arabic (perhaps because they have requested Arabic, then German, then English, and you don't localize to Arabic).

So what you may mean is `[NSLocale preferredLanguages]`. You can search through that and decide how to behave. But in almost all cases, the better answer is to just add an extra identifier into your localization bundle and see what you get back. For example, if in your German `Localizeable.strings` file you have:

```
MY_LOCALE = "German";
```

you can then use:

```
NSString *identifier = [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:@"MY_LOCALE" value:nil table:nil];
if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"German"]) { ... }
```

That said, it is incredibly rare that you should do this. Apple provides a [rich localization and internationalization system](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Introduction/Introduction.html) to avoid you ever doing this. Unless you have a very specialized and unusual problem, looking up the language is probably the wrong thing to be doing.

And as I said, "German" is not a localization. It's a language, and there are many other "local" things beyond language (such as date formatting, number formatting, etc.) If you need the whole localization, you want to use `[[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier]`. You can then use `+componentsFromLocaleIdentifier:` to tear it apart and deal with the various parts if that's absolutely necessary.